# Find the Java Exe path dynamically for the action tab of task schedule

Tags: java

I need to make JRE path dynamic for the action tab of task scheduler. Currently one of our application has been scheuled under tasks has the hard coded JRE path and in the action tab under task manager as below:

Action Tab: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"  "XYZ.war"**

This is causing problem whenever there is a upgradation in JRE version is happening. Can we make the action tab to detect JRE tab dynamically in task scheduler or we should go for other approcach?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards
Prashant

Comment: You mean you want to pass `JRE` dynamically in Java or in windows scheduler ?

Comment: In scheduler .. Like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" should be dynamic. The server should search for the installed path and update in the task scheduler. I am not sure whether we can do it.

Answer (score 0):

For that case use Environment or system variables as configuration for your JRE

Set a variable in Environment and call that Variable in Scheduler

I think the below link is answer you are looking for
[Pass Environmet Dynamically to Scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/331077/accessing-environment-variables-in-a-scheduled-task)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. looks like this is the link for which I was searching. I will verify and vote it as answer.